# Zabbix: adding items make agents not available

Tags: zabbix

Zabbix version: 3.0.3 (zabbix-server-mysql)

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Number of hosts (enabled/disabled/templates): 28 / 0 / 57

Number of items (enabled/disabled/not supported): 1349 / 161 / 47

Number of triggers (enabled/disabled): 902 / 39

Required server performance, new values per second: 22.86

Zabbix server config:

`StartPollers=5
StartPollersUnreachable=2
StartTrappers=5
StartDiscoverers=3
StartHTTPPollers=5`

I have template with 3 items like this: `net.tcp.port[<IP>,3128]`. Template is applied to 10 servers.

Here is problem: when I enable this items, events like `zabbix-agent on <hostname> is not available for 2 minutes` start to randomly appear on 10 hosts where template is applied. Values on graph "Zabbix Server Preformance" (that represents ), representing `zabbix[wcache,values]`, start going down from 19-19.5 to 16-17. Values representing `zabbix[queue]` stay at 0 as before.

When I disable items, problem disappears.

Zabbix server is not overloaded by I/O or CPU, there is plenty of free memory. Doesn't seem as hardware performance issue. Zabbix agents on hosts are available, I check it with `nc -vz <hostname> 10050`.

Nothing abnormal appears in server log or agents logs on this 10 hosts.

I tried increasing `ulimit -n` for zabbix server process, it was increased: `cat /proc/<zabbix_worker_pid>/limits` now shows `Max open files 10240 10240 files`. Didn't help.

I tried increasing number of StartPollers to 10 and 15 - didn't help either.

What is happening to server?

**UPD**:

Items type: Zabbix agent

All systems are rinning Linux ubuntu 14.04 trusty

Agents on hosts run 3 listeners, 1 collector and 1 active checks process.

For 7 of this 10 hosts `zabbix_get -s <host> -t net.tcp.port[<IP>,3128]` works instantly for all 3 items, on other 3 hosts it works for about 3 seconds and returns 0(monitored IPs are not available from that 3 hosts).

Comment: What's the item type ? What's the busy rate for pollers and unreachable pollers ? How many listeners are started on each agent ?

Comment: If you use `zabbix_get`, how long does it take for agents to process `net.tcp.port[]` items? Are these agents running on Windows or a Unix-like system?

Comment: @asaveljevs: updated description.

Comment: @Richlv: updated description. How can I check busy rate for pollers and unreachable pollers?

Comment: To check process busyness, use `zabbix[process,poller,avg,busy]` and `zabbix[process,unreachable poller,avg,busy]` internal items (see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/internal). They are included in the default "Template App Zabbix Server" that ships with Zabbix.

Comment: I reported problem in zabbix tracker: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-10868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally:

If:

- timeout on both agent and server are the same (default: timeout = 3)
- there is item `net.tcp.port[<IP>,<port>]` and trigger using it
- pair `[<IP>,<port>]` is unavailable by TCP timeout

Then:

"Zabbix-agent on {HOST.NAME} is unawailable" ( trigger expression:
`{agent.ping.nodata(2m)} = 1` ) start spawning on hosts with this item. Not the trigger for specific item, but the trigger for the **agent availability**. This is **bug**, but zabbix guys do not seem to agree:

https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-10868

Zabbix version 3.0.3 for both server and agent.

Possible workarounds:

- make Timeout in zabbix_server.conf more than in zabbix_agentd.conf
- use UserParameter like this: `UserParameter=tcp_connect_check[*], /bin/nc -z "$1" "$2" -w "$3"; echo $?` and create items connect timeout less than in zabbix_agentd.conf. To avoid securely problems, do not enable `UnsafeUserParameters` in zabbix_agentd.conf